# Not able to upload as anonymous user in vsftpd

Tags: permissions, ftp, vsftpd, umask, upload

I have vsftpd running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

During installation a ftp user is created with a home directory of /srv/ftp and hence this is the default FTP directory.

Here are my vsftpd.conf file permissions that I've set.

```
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
anon_umask=011
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
```

What I'm trying to do is upload files as an anonymous user to the ftp server. I am able to login as an anonymous user but when I'm trying to upload, I'm getting,

```
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
553 Could not create file.
```

Now there are numerous sources on the internet who are getting the same error but none of the solutions are solving my error. I know there is something about the permissions that I'm missing.

The /srv/ftp permissions are set to 755.

Comment: "... are getting the same error but none of the solutions are solving my error".  Do you expect someone here to go through all of those options again?  From [How to ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) -  Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed vsftpd, filezilla, went through your .conf and added options accordingly:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf | grep -v "#"
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chown_uploads=YES
chown_username=abdullah
xferlog_std_format=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES

pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

filezilla did give some feedback and I had to change the option ***chown_username=abdullah*** with my existing user name.

then I run into permission problem, which is solved by changing the ownership of the ftp folder **/var/ftp/pub** from **root** to **ftp**.
Then, I was able to upload & bind the files but not modify them, since we have a umask option.